# "Intent" and "purport"

Tags: word-choice, meaning, synonyms

I was unable to understand the similarities and differences between *intent* and *purport*. A description will be good to understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Purport" usually has a negative connotation of falsely conveying a certain meaning while "Intent" is more neutral.

For example,

The **purport** of this book is to present an objective take on abortion, although in actual fact, it leans heavily on anti-abortion viewpoints.

The **intent** of this book is to present an objective take on abortion.

Comment: +1, though it bears mentioning that "purport" is more commonly found as a verb than as a noun.

Answer (score 3):

As reported from the NOAD, the meaning of the words, when used as nouns, is the following:

- intent: intention or purpose
- purport: the meaning or substance of something, typically a document or speech

> With alarm she realized his intent.
>   A real intent to cut back on social programs.

> I do not understand the purport of your remarks.

The meaning of *purport* as verb is "appear or claim to be or do something, especially falsely", "profess".

> She is not the person she purports to be.

Answer (score 0):

*Intent* is a concept that shapes action, but it is not action.

> - My intent is to be sympathetic to her cause.
> - My intent was to hit the nail with the hammer.

*Purport*, as a noun, means to carry or transmit the gist of something, either literally or implicitly.

> The purport of the research was given in the abstract.

As a transitive verb, *purport* gives voice to 3rd person hearsay (as in *report*) rather than direct transmission, and is usually interpreted as *supposed* or *alleged*.

> - She is purported to be an expert. (active)
> - It is purported that she is an expert. (passive)

Very interesting question about the dual meaning of *purport*. I'm not sure how intent is involved.

Comment: Both your last examples are passive. "She is purported" and "it is purported" is the exact same structure.

Comment: Purport *as a noun* does not mean "to do" anything.  "The intended (possibly specious) meaning" would be a better definition.